# Shifted divs still take up original space?

Tags: html, css

Ok, so on my website, I have nested divs. Using my code, I shift them like so:

```
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    top: 5em;
    left: -4em;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
```

So, when the website loads, everything is in the right place. However, other content is still affected by where the div USED to be. Which, I'll just refer to as a "ghost div"

I'm sure this is a common problem, but I have no idea how to phrase it properly so I have been unable to search for the right issue.

Example:
[image: Ghost Div]

Comment: Sorry yoda, I'm working locally. The code isn't very long at all (I just started) I'd be more than happy to post it if you'd like.

Comment: I run an HTTP server on all my machines for exactly this. I hate running things without an HTTP server anyways, local files always have weird restrictions.

Comment: Are you [clearing your floats](http://css-tricks.com/containers-dont-clear-floats/)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's exactly what position: relative; is supposed to do. If you want the element to not participate in layout, use position: absolute; instead. You can make that relative to another element by making one of its parents a positioned element (for instance, by applying position: relative; without any coordinates)

Comment: Wow, thanks for the tip. I never knew that relative kept the "space" and absolute didn't!

Comment: or else, keep position relative and use negative margins.. not sure if this may be the case, though..

Answer (score 3):

Matti is right.

Also, what you probably want to do is this:

Make the container element's position: relative (but don't put any top/left/right/bottom on that)
Make this element you're trying to move:  position: absolute;

Then your coordinates of the element get set relative to the container element.

When I say "container" element, I mean whatever element it is that wraps this element you're trying to move.

So if your HTML code is like this:

```
<div id="header">
    <div id="weird-symbol"><img src="/symbo.gif" /></div>
    .. some other stuff ..
</div>
```

Then your CSS should be something like:

```
#header { position: relative; }
#header #weird-symbol { position: absolute; left: -200px; top: 30px; }
```

or something like that.

Hope it helps